# Why doesn't my socket receive the response?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I opened a regular java socket in my android app, and I have to use it to send requests and receive responses, I am sending the requests normally but don't receive any response from the server, I checked the server connections and it's alright and also I tried to listen via  [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html/) and the requests are sent normally and the server sends the responses normally, this is the regular socket coding I'm using:

```
public static void xbmc_connect(){
    try {
        xbmc_socket = new Socket(xbmc_address, xbmc_port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void xbmc_sendingDataToSystem(String data) throws IOException{

    xbmc_output = new DataOutputStream(xbmc_socket.getOutputStream());
    xbmc_output.writeBytes(data);

}

public String xbmc_getServerResponse() throws JSONException{

    String responseLine, server_response = null_string;

      try {
          xbmc_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    xbmc_socket.getInputStream()));
          System.out.println(xbmc_input.toString());// doesn't print anything
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  try {
        while ((responseLine = xbmc_input.readLine()) != null) {
            server_response = server_response + responseLine ;
      }

            return server_response;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: `xbmc_input` is a `BufferedReader`. ***To read from a BufferedReader, you have to use either `read()` or `readLine()`***.

It doesn't make much sense to get the `String` representation of the BufferedReader with `toString()` as you are doing. **Calling `toString()` does not make the `BufferedReader` print anything that it may have received. `toString()` simply prints the `BufferedReader` object** - ***that is, a reference to the object***.

Therefore, to print what was actually received (if anything), you may want to try:

```
System.out.println(xbmc_input.readLine());
```

Comment: i just put it for testing , i don't want it to print anything readable, i just want it to give me any result which makes me know it receives anything, and by the way i made i print it with reading line like that and also gives nothing

Comment: Printing the BufferedReader with toString() doesn't tell you whether it's received anything. You have to call `read()` or `readLine()`. However, I see now that you do do this in the while loop at least.  In your catch statement above it, do `e.printStackTrace()` to make sure that no exception is being thrown.